# mvc application with razor data view engine problems with the url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I create a new mhc application with razor data view engine. I have a problems with the url

Here is my action links

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index")
@Html.ActionLink("Schedule", "Schedule")
```

After I loaded home page my url looks fine

Example: mysiteurl.com

Then I click Schedule link (if I hover I see the correct url http://mysiteurl.com/home/schedule). If I click it as a result my url  will http://mysiteurl.com//#/Home/Schedule. I don't know why its adding # sign to my url but it's causing the issue in my application with other pages.

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I don't have any custom routing 
here is my RegisterRoutes method in Global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
```

Comment: Do you have any custom routing rules defined?

Comment: Rather than clicking the link, does the same happen if you type the URL by hand? Also, does the incorrect URL actually return the page?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ActionLinks` look fine. I'd guess you have at least one custom route defined inside your `RegisterRoutes` method. I'd guess you've got a typo somewhere in there.

You could try installing [Glimpse](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Glimpse) via NuGet - it allows you to see exactly which routing rules are firing. Scott Hanselman has [this blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek5DebuggingASPNETMVCApplicationsWithGlimpse.aspx) on how to use it.

Comment: Looks ok, does your Schedule action redirect to anything?

Comment: OK, I think I found what causing the problem. I'm using jquery mobile library  and if I remove the reference it works. the problem I need to use them <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.js"></script>

Comment: This link looks like it may have the answer: [Subpages Not Loading Via Ajax in A4](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/subpages-not-loading-via-ajax-in-a4)

Comment: in my case I'm able to load page but the url has #

Comment: I'm out of ideas - it might still be worth running Glimpse - it has a host of other useful tools besides route debugging that might help. I suggest you update your question with the new info, hopefully someone else might be able to help.